# Why I get TransactionRequired exception even method saving entity is annotated with @Transactional？

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

I get an exception when I upload picture

**Methods**

```
 public ServiceResult uploadPortrait( MultipartFile file,int userId){
    if (file.getSize()>ConfigurationHolder.getPictureSize()) {
        return ServiceResult.getErrorResult("exceed 2M!");
    }else{
        String filename=file.getOriginalFilename();
        String subfix=FileType.getSuffixByFilename(filename);
        if(ConfigurationHolder.getPortraitFileType().contains(subfix)){
            String inLibPath=ConfigurationHolder.getUserPortraitInLibPath(userId, subfix);
            try { 
                savePortraitToDataBase(inLibPath, userId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return ServiceResult.getErrorResult("saveError！");
            }
            ServiceResult result=ServiceResult.getSuccessResult("changeSuccess！");
            result.putProperty("portraitPath", inLibPath);
            return result;
        }else{
            return ServiceResult.getErrorResult("file type must be one of jpg,png,jpeg or gif！");
        }
    }
}
@Transactional(value="account",rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public void savePortraitToDataBase(String inLibPath, int userId){
    userOthersRepos.updatePortait(userId,inLibPath);
    userOthersdao.savePortraitToRedis(inLibPath, userId);
}
```

**Exception**

```
Caused by:exception'stacktrace:Caused by:javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:96)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:372)
        at $Proxy118.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:174)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:61)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:95)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:85)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:323)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        ... 79 more
```

When I add the `@Transactional` annotation to `uploadPortrait()` and remove it from `savePortraitToDataBase()` , it works.

Can somebody tell me why?

Comment: Short version: This is a *self-call* (it's internal to the class), so Spring can't apply the same decoration it does when you call a bean (which it wraps up before injecting).

Answer (score 0):

In the above code fragment you are invoking "savePortraitToDataBase" method from "uploadPortrait" and before this invocation you invoke  "userOthersdao.savePortrait". It seems to me that the exception which you are getting is because of the invocation of userOthersdao.savePortrait(as it might also be doing insert/update operation and transaction is missing in case @Transactional is placed over savePortraitToDataBase this method).

But in the other way around when you place @Transactional over "uploadPortrait" function, transaction is available to both the methods.

Answer (score 0):

To elborate on @chrylis's comment, the "Transactional" annotation is a Spring decorator - it only applies when something calls from outside the class to your function via an injected (or "autowired", in spring terminology) bean. Calling from inside the same class doesn't have the same effect

Comment: and @ chrylis thank you very much! I go to add a new `@service` class